# nest e74 code but its just heat no air

Tags: nest

i installed the nest thermostat as instruction say i get the e74 code i checked fuse.turned power off an on  now what is happening is when i attach the thermostat tothe base my relays flash quickly making a clicking noise; it is a zoned set up with two thermostats the other one works fine and its not a nest its still my original one its just the new nest. would appreciate any suggestions thank you and this is just heat unit i have no air

Comment: What make and model is your furnace, and can you post its wiring diagram + photos of the wiring at both ends of the thermostat cable?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info before we can help. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.